# How to display automatically generated PDF thumbnails in wordpress media library?

Tags: wordpress, pdf, thumbnails, media-library

I have an issue with displaying thumbnails of PDF's in Wordpress media library (as separate file not while displaying PDF). Thumbnails are automatically generated in wordpress media folder on my FTP in three various resolutions as .jpg's but I cant see them in media library. I would like to use them elsewhere on website, so I won't have to upload 'extra' images to each pdf. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question should include a clear outline of your *specific* coding-related issue, a summary of what you have already tried and the relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we have enough information to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

i read this and based on that when thumbnail generate for your pdf you need to create post for that images with post type as attachment.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But how can I create post for that images? As I posted before I cant navigate to them through media library.

Comment: You already mention Thumbnails are automatically generated in wordpress media folder on my FTP in three various resolutions as .jpg's but I cant see them in media library. So you just need to create proper entry in db for that images as attachment so you get that images on media library as well